# add class to element returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id="er_msg" style="width:200px;" align="center"></div>
```

I am adding a class to the above `div` with JavaScript:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["form1"]["email_id"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        document.getElementById("er_msg").innerHTML="Pls enter a valid E-Mail Address ";
        document.getElementById("er_msg").className="alert alert-error";

     }else{
         document.getElementById("er_msg").innerHTML="Thank you!";
         document.getElementById("er_msg").className="alert alert-success";
         saveAppdata();


     }
}
```

Ideally I should get a red colored  `"Pls enter a valid E-Mail Address"` and a green `"Thank you!"`, whereas in this case both messages appear in red. The classes are predefined by Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: What is the `alert` class?

Comment: Isn't the align attributes deprecated?

Comment: At first glance, I'd say the `alert` class is setting `color: #F00;`. Please show the CSS rules, too. And if I'm right, either set the `color` in the `alert-error` and `alert-success` classes, or add `color:#0F0;!important` to the `alert-success` class

Comment: When you are testing this, are you getting the error message "valid e-mail address" first, then enter a valid and get the Thank you? If so, it's red because you aren't removing the alert-error class.

Comment: @JayGee - The code shown removes the class, because it overwrites _all_ classes for the element in both the if and the else branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your javascript function using Twitter bootstraps css classes and it works without a problem.

Here is my jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/yqRCX/

Here are the css classes:

```
.alert {
    padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert, .alert h4 {
    color: #c09853;
}
.alert h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
.alert .close {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    right: -21px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.alert-success {
    color: #468847;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.alert-success h4 {
    color: #468847;
}
.alert-danger, .alert-error {
    color: #b94a48;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.alert-danger h4, .alert-error h4 {
    color: #b94a48;
}
```

So the answer is.. I don't see any problem with the code you have supplied. Your add class works.

If you have other problems please supply more information like what e-mail values you are trying and such.